# Why isn't my sprite moving when i press a specific key in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d, game-physics

I was building a simple rocket game and it required moving some sprites. In the code below cloud1 is supposed to move -30 pixels towards the bottom each time i press the K_DOWN key. I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with the code for 3 days but haven't progressed even a little bit. Help would be much appreciated.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 700
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Rocket Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60


#colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SKY_BLUE = (102,178,255)

cloud1 = pygame.image.load('cloud.png')
cloud1_X, cloud1_Y = 100, 50
cloud1_Y_change = 30


def cloud1_display(x, y):
    screen.blit(cloud1, (x, y))

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(SKY_BLUE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                cloud1_Y += cloud1_Y_change

    cloud1_display(cloud1_X, cloud1_X)
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: That shouldn't cause any problems, since python will still interpret the second value in the tuple as a y-value, although the variable name says otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.  The first is that your code is not checking the `event.key` for the `pygame.K_UP`.  But your code is also painting the cloud at `(x, x)`, not `(x, y)`.

Corrected code:

```
while running:
    screen.fill(SKY_BLUE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:       # <<-- HERE
                cloud1_Y += cloud1_Y_change

    cloud1_display(cloud1_X, cloud1_Y)         # <<-- AND HERE
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

For you main game loop try to use `event.key` instead of `event.type` for the second time. Like so:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            cloud1_Y += cloud1_Y_change
```

Another issue that I have noticed is that your not converting your image to a rect object in pygame and then use `.blit` to show it onscreen. The `.blit` function requires a rect object argument, so that's why your having issues.

```
cloud1 = pygame.image.load('asteroid_pic.bmp')
rect =  cloud1.get_rect()
screen.blit(cloud1, self.rect)
```

I also recommend creating separate classes for your sprites, so that its easier to keep track of them and if you want to create duplicates of the same one but still retain the same characteristics of the single class sprite you can do so by importing the function `Group` from `pygame.sprite`.

Comment: Sorry, i tried it and it is not working. But thank you, saved me from another error.

Comment: Hope what I added helps